# How to align WPF TabControl headers to right side?

Tags: wpf

I attached my control image . Here i need to align my Tab Control headers to align right side position in WPF.
[My Tab Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5RVS.png)

**My Code:**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DockPanel x:Name="headerPanel"  Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem x:Name="tabItem" Header="TabItem" Height="50">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
```

Above code default tab control code in WPF with full template code. i tried Strip Option too it is also not work for me.
Guys you can understand my problem. So if any doubt means comment me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **HorizontalAlignment** to your Dockpanel:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="headerPanel" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" <--here
           Background="Transparent"
           Grid.Column="0"
           IsItemsHost="true"
           Margin="2,2,2,0" 
           Grid.Row="0"
           KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
           Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
```